# What does ionic serve executes in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, gulp, webpack, ionic2

I've been trying to add a gulp task to compile jade files I'm creating.

The tasks is working fine, however, when I run `ionic serve` it doesn't execute the gulp task I created

I assume that Ionic is using webpack, however I'd like to know what I need to do to make my new task work as well

The output I got is:

```
➜  ionic git:(master) ✗ ionic serve

∆ Compiling and bundling with Webpack...
√ Using your webpack.config.js file

∆ Compiling Sass to CSS
√ Matching patterns: app/theme/app.+(ios|md|wp).scss

∆ Copying fonts
√ Matching patterns: node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts/**/*.+(ttf|woff|woff2)

∆ Copying HTML
√ Matching patterns: app/**/*.html

√ HTML copied to www/build
√ Sass compilation complete
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Ionic2 documentation regarding [app-scripts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/), they have decided not to use gulp in their project any longer:

> **What About Gulp?**
>
> Historically Ionic apps have used gulp as tool to facilitate the build
>   process. Over the years, gulp has seen less and less development, and
>   has started to accumulate deprecation warnings. By taking advantage of
>   standard and dependency free NPM scripts, we are reducing dependencies
>   and simplifying the development experience.

Instead they are using Ionic app scripts, that are indeed npm scripts for their build process. From the same mentioned doc:

> When `ionic serve` or `ionic run` are invoked, it ultimately calls an NPM
>   script. These npm scripts call the @ionic/app-scripts library to
>   execute the build process.

To accomplish your goal, i.e. to use **Pug** (formerly known as **Jade**) for the templates, you may do either of the following:

**One:** Write a custom app script instead of `watch.config.js`. The original script is available on [here on github](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/watch.config.js).

**Two:** Write a [Cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/) for *before_compile*.

---

As a reference this answer is written on 2016-Nov-12.